# What types of files can be cached in Firefox

Tags: firefox, browser, internet, cache

Is there a limited set of filetypes that firefox will choose to save to browsing cache or can any filetype theoretically be cached? obviously images, scripts, and other media make sense but could a website also force the browser to save things like zip files or exes?

Answer (score 0):

For MIME types listed in /handlers.json, you can choose whether certain file types are to be saved, to be opened by a specific application, or handled some other way. Though some MIME types are already listed in *about:preferences*, you can add more types by editing handlers.json.

[image: Firefox MIME handler]

This allows *you* to decide how file types are processed. In the screenshot, note that I've changed handling of *EPUB file*, so that all those goodies on [Project Gutenberg](https://www.gutenberg.org/) or the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/search.php) can be saved to the default location with a single click.

AFAIK, there is no way to store an *active* executable file in the [caches](https://www.anyrecover.com/deleted-files-recovery-data/firefox-cache-location/), e.g. in Windows 10:

- C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\<profile\cache2\entries
- C:\Users\<user>\AppData\LocalLow\Mozilla\temp*xxxxx*

That said, it might be possible to store such inside another file, such as an image, through [steganography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steganography).